# Application of the semi-direct product

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

how would you prove that 
$Z/30Z$ x  $Z/7Z \simeq Z/210Z$ using the semi direct product?

I know that if |G|=pq, (p and q primes) there exist an homomorphism $\phi: C_p --> Aut C_q $ such that G $\simeq$  $C_q$  X  $C_p $ 
(Where 'X' is the semi direct product and $ \simeq$ means 'isomorphic')
Thanks !

Comment: Compute the automorphism group of $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$ and show that there are no nonzero maps into it from $\mathbb{Z}_7$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Im not sure i understand how to do that...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Can you explain more?

Comment: You do not have to compute the automorphism group of $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$, only its cardinal...

Comment: @ClémentGuérin please give me more details.. i am lost.